# How does response work inside callback in Express/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an async function which fetches some data from a file and then calls the callback function to return the result:

```
    static fetchAll(callback){
        fs.readFile(pathToDB, (err, fileContent) => {
            if(err){
                callback([]);
                return;
            }
            callback(JSON.parse(fileContent));
        });
    }
```

Then I call that function in one of my route controller functions by passing in the callback that triggers the res.render() when data is received:

```
const getShop = (req, res, next) => {
    Product.fetchAll(products => {
        console.log("Products received!, rendering");
        res.render('shop', { prods: products, pageTitle: 'Shop', path: '/'});
    });
    console.log("leaving!");
};
```

My questions are:

1. How does express/node know to wait for the callback function to finish and then call res.render() without using something like async/await or Promises? (how are callbacks inside callbacks handled in node)
2. Would it better to use Promises in this context? (other than having the advantage of having .then() and .catch() )

Comment: I would use the promise version instead `readFileSync`. Then you can use async/await or .then()

Comment: Are you referring to [the Node.js event loop](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-loop)?

Comment: "*How does express/node know to wait for the callback …*" - it doesn't "know" anything about when `res.render` will happen. It also doesn't "wait" for anything. It's just that the `readFile` thing finishes at some points, fires the callback function, which in turn calls the callback function that calls `res.render()`. When this happens, express is happy and closes the connection. Otherwise, it'll just hang.

Comment: And yes, promises would be totally appropriate in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Bergi, my context of saying 'wait' was referring to the event loop and how does the order of execution change since it seems that the 'res' function now became dependent to the callback function because I used it inside it. (which results it in res 'waiting' for it to be completed).

Comment: `res` doesn't know where it is used. Order of execution does not "change", it just *is*.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't wait for the callback. It will `console.log("leaving!")` *before* `console.log("Products received!, rendering")`. Only after the file is read then its data is passed to the `res.render` section. But by then Node has moved on.

Promises and callbacks are the same thing under the hood. So it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , my context of saying 'wait' was referring to the event loop and how does the order of execution/dependency change since it seems that the 'res' function now became dependent to the callback function because I used it inside it. (which results it in res 'waiting' for it to be completed).